# Setting checked property true for the non existing DOM elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm new to React and working on the Select All functionality for a table.

```
    this.state.selectedAccounts = [];
    this.props.accountList.forEach((account, index) => {
        var row = document.getElementById('accountSelection_' + index);
        if (row !== null) {
            row.checked = checked;
```

This is how I'm looping over the selected accounts of the table and passing the checked parameter.

Now, the issue is in the case of pagination, only the accounts that are in current page return the DOM element

```
document.getElementById('accountSelection_' + index);
```

, so I can only pass the checked parameter to those and only those check boxes are selected.
For the accounts in next page

```
document.getElementById('accountSelection_' + index);
```

returns null, so couldn't pass the checked parameter.

The library used doesn't provide any event on selecting pages, so couldn't capture the page change event and pass the Checked parameter to new rows in the view. I want Select all the Check boxes at once.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what library of pagination your are using ? It will be way more easy to answer you.

My guess on your issue is that your pagination library populate the DOM only with your visible elements. It means that your items in the others pages are simply not in the DOM and that would explain why they are not recoverable by the `document.getElementById` function.

I see different ways of resolving your issue :

1. Find another pagination library or make your own implementation of
   a simple pagination that hide the items of other pages with CSS.
   This would populate the dom with your items and make them
   recoverable. Note that this kind of resolution is absolutely not
   optimized and can lead of performances issues if you are dealing
   with a lot of items.
2. If your are sending your items via props to your pagination library, that means that your items are stored in your pagination library main component state. Find in the library documentation if there is no ways to checks items by changing an intern property.
3. Do the check by yourself. You can add to your items an additional property like `isChecked`, and manually check them all or uncheck them all. Then, when you are rendering your items, you can check if the intern `isChecked` property of a specific item is marked as checked or not. Based on that, you can easily mark an item as checked. If you cannot control directly how items are rendered by your library, try to find is there is a prop that can allow you to overload the item rendering method of your library like a `onRenderingItem` prop. Here is a more visual representation of what im saying :

```js
// Item interface
interface Item {
  name: string;
  isChecked: boolean
}

// Rendering
{items.map((item: Item) => 
 <button checked={isChecked} >{name}</button> 
)}
```

Hope that i've helped you at least a little. Feel free to answer me :)

Happy coding !

Comment: Hi!

We are using { MDBTable, MDBTableHead, MDBTableBody } from 'mdbreact'

1. This is a huge project using this library only, so changing the common functionality might not be the case.

2. Since we are using different libraries fro checkboxes and for data table, I don't think it will be possible to bind to some property of the data.
Checkboxes are clicked when onChange on row generates an event for the checkbox to turn true.

Comment: Ok. But is the checked value of your CheckBoxes are intern state of the component or you have to pass the checked state of your items to the CheckBox component ? 
What Checkboxes library are you using ?

Comment: `import { MDBInput } from "mdbreact";

class CheckboxIntl extends Component{
    render(){
        const { name, id, label, value, onChange, tabIndex, containerClass, className, labelClass, ...rest } = this.props;
        return (
            <MDBInput
                name={name}
                id={id || name}
                type={'checkbox'}
                label={label}
                checked={value}
                onChange={onChange}
                {...rest}
            />
        )
    }
}`

Comment: OK, so as you can see, your checkboxes have a `checked` prop. That means your items have to own the attribute that indicate if they are checked or not. If you take back my sample of my original answer with my `Item` interface and if you have an array of it. As you can see, items have now an attribute `isChecked` that can you change to marker them as checked. Simply send this to the `checked`attribute of your checkbox.
Then, if you want to mark all your items as checked, you simply have to loop over your items array and pass the `isChecked` attribute of each of your items to true.

Comment: One thing to note in React is that you are very rarely supposed to manipulate and mutate the dom directly. Since React use a virtual DOM and compare it to the original DOM, it can lead to strange behaviours. Please avoid this and always try to find alternative and React compliant solutions.

Comment: SO this is how ceck boxes will be selected in my case?

    `handleSelectAllCheckBox = (checked) => {

           return <CheckboxIntl id="accountSelection_1" name="accountSelection_1" checked={checked}></CheckboxIntl>`

Comment: Nope. I'm not sure if what im writing is clear, so i've made you a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tck0f5vp/. Hope it will helps you !